# Multiple Honor Ribbons in League of Legends

Tags: league-of-legends

I logged on to League today and found that I had received another honor ribbon(the blue one for being a helpful player). I already had earned the green ribbon for teamwork but now all I see is my blue one.

My question is, is there a way to change which ribbon you have showing or are you stuck showing the last ribbon you earned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They go in order of how many people have the ribbon.
Basically the ribbon that will show up when you have multiple ribbons should be the best/rarest one.

Comment: So am I stuck showing that ribbon regardless, or is there a way to change which one is showing, your answer really didn't address my question.

Comment: You're stuck with it. I just assumed that's quite obvious.

Comment: (It was quite obvious don't worry). Yeah, I'm stuck with blue too since no one honors "helpful", most people just do "teamwork". I had the red honorable opponent, but then that got replaced by the green "leader", and now its blue "helpful". Since there are exactly four ribbons I think they should show all the ones you have, just one in each corner. Apparently though, so I've heard, you get a rainbow ribbon if you have all four. Not sure if its true, never seen one. A buddy said his buddy has one, but I have never played with that buddy, I can't confirm that.

Comment: I would like the four corner idea as well.  I've also heard of people with all four getting a different one but I've never seen it either. Personally I think it is rather silly that I only had 8 helpful honor and got the blue ribbon, when it took me close to 100 teamwork to get the green. >.>

Comment: I have all of them you do not get a rainbow. Mine show's up blue as well.